# Accessibility Scanner issue: No readable label for Flutter apps

Tags: flutter, screen-readers, accessibility

Why I did a accessibility analysis on flutter app getting message as follows:

> This item may not have a label readable by screen readers.

[image]

My widget has this code:

```
Semantics(
  label: 'Login page.',
  child: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
    body: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
      child: Center(
        child: Text("My app!!!", style: labelTextStyle, semanticsLabel: 'app of semantic',)
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Hi, I have the sam problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Accessibility Scanner doesn't work with Flutter apps yet, despite Google recommending it in [official Flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/accessibility#inspecting-accessibility-support).

You can keep tabs on support for it via [Flutter issue #39531](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39531).

Answer (score 1):

I work closely with a friend who is blind and uses screens readers to code and use his phone.

Using `Semantics` on top of an Scaffold would make the whole page to only say the label (in your case `Login Page.`) So the Accessibility Inspector is telling you that one of the labels (the `Text`'s one) will not be readable by screens readers because the `Semantics` is over of it.

Comment: Even when there isn't a Semantics widget over it, Accessibility Scanner just does not seem to work for me, even though it's recommended in official documentation: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/accessibility.